# Elegant way to plot a probability density function?

Tags: probability, matlab, density-function

Given a set of samples I would like to draw a nice plot showing their probability. Something like this (notice the vertical bar showing the samples): [image]

Or even harder like this (considering a weight for each sample):

[image]

Can Matlab do this? Or would you suggest other tools?

Comment: The "vertical bar showing the samples" is commonly known as a ["rugplot"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875341).

Comment: I'd presume Matlab can do it, but I know for certain you can do the first kind directly in R using `plot(density(x));rug(x)`. The second one you'd have to write several lines of R to achieve, but it's easily doable.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the rug plot in the bottom graphic trying to show?  It seems to be displaying two varying quantities (a sequence of discrete values given by the horizontal locations of the ticks and another parallel series given by the lengths of the ticks), neither of which looks like it has much to do with the "proposal" or "target."

Answer (score 2):

There are rug plot functions on the MATLAB File Exchange, though I've never tried them. Here's a simple few lines of MATLAB to get something that looks like the first example:

```
x = [randn(100,1); 3+.5*randn(50,1)];
ksdensity(x)
hold on; h=stem(x,-.05*ones(size(x)),'k-','Marker','none'); hold off
```